# Drupal 6 - Add the View Name to the Body Class

Tags: css, drupal-6, view

In Drupal 6 (when using Views), by default, each View is wrapped in a DIV. This DIV contains a number of classes that describe the name and type of the View.

Is there anyway to output these classes in the body tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't find a way to access the existing views classes applied to other elements, but I do what the Zen theme does, which is to use the first argument of any URL as a body class e.g. yoursite.com/case-studies would have the body class "page-case-studies". This normally does the trick, as it is often set to be the title of the view. It can also easily be adapted/customised for specific cases.

You can achieve this with 3 lines in your THEME_preprocess_page() function, in your theme's template.php:

```
$path = drupal_get_path_alias($_GET['q']);
list($title, ) = explode('/', $path, 2);
$vars['body_classes'] .= " ".drupal_html_class("page-".$title);
```

For more functionality, you can just download the [Zen theme](http://drupal.org/project/zen), and have a look at their template.php.

Obviously make sure that your page.tpl.php is printing $body_classes. Also to use this on Drupal 6, you need to copy the drupal_html_class() function, which is also included in Zen's template.php.